# TSQL to insert a set of rows and dependent rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, set-based

I have 2 tables:

- Order (with a identity order id field)
- OrderItems (with a foreign key to order id)

In a stored proc, I have a list of orders that I need to duplicate.  Is there a good way to do this in a stored proc **without** a cursor?

---

Edit:

This is on SQL Server 2008.

A sample spec for the table might be:

```
CREATE TABLE Order (
   OrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   CustomerName VARCHAR(100),
   CONSTRAINT PK_Order PRIMARY KEY (OrderID)
)

CREATE TABLE OrderItem (
   OrderID INT,
   LineNumber INT,
   Price money,
   Notes VARCHAR(100),
   CONSTRAINT PK_OrderItem PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, LineNumber),
   CONSTRAINT FK_OrderItem_Order FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Order(OrderID)
)
```

The stored proc is passed a customerName of 'fred', so its trying to clone all orders where CustomerName = 'fred'.

To give a more concrete example:

Fred happens to have 2 orders:

- Order 1 has line numbers 1,2,3
- Order 2 has line numbers 1,2,4,6.

If the next identity in the table was 123, then I would want to create:

- Order 123 with lines 1,2,3
- Order 124 with lines 1,2,4,6

Comment: How are you passing in your list?  And what version of SQL Server?

Comment: By duplicating, do you mean writing the same information into the same table, but with different ID's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On SQL Server 2008 you can use `MERGE` and the `OUTPUT` clause to get the mappings between the original and cloned `id` values from the insert into `Orders` then join onto that to clone the OrderItems.

```
DECLARE @IdMappings TABLE(
  New_OrderId INT,
  Old_OrderId INT)  

;WITH SourceOrders AS
(
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerName = 'fred'
)
MERGE Orders AS T
USING SourceOrders AS S
ON 0 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (CustomerName )
  VALUES (CustomerName )
OUTPUT inserted.OrderId,
       S.OrderId INTO @IdMappings;  

INSERT INTO OrderItems
SELECT New_OrderId,
       LineNumber,
       Price,
       Notes
FROM   OrderItems OI
       JOIN @IdMappings IDM
         ON IDM.Old_OrderId = OI.OrderID
```